# I need help, when i update a specifci node in firebase with Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database:

[image: My database]

I need update de "Foto" node, but when I use this code in android, it does not work:

[image]

**Create Node in "Usuarios"**

```
private void CrearUsuariodb(String uid,String Nombre,String Telefono) {
       User user=new User("0",Nombre,Telefono,"0",uid);
       myRef.child(Uidt).setValue(user);
}
```

**Call Set ActualizarFotodb**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(requestCode==GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
{
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Subiendo Foto...");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Subiendo Foto a Firebase");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();

   Uri uri=data.getData();
    String uidt=user.getUid();



    StorageReference filePath=mStorage.child(uidt).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
   filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

           mProgressDialog.dismiss();
           Uri descargarFoto=taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

           //REGISTRAR EN METODO DE BASE DE DATOS

           String dinnyfoto=descargarFoto.toString();


           setActualizarFotodb(dinnyfoto);



           Intent Inicio =new Intent(EscogerFoto.this, VisualizarFoto.class);
           startActivity(Inicio);
           Toast.makeText(EscogerFoto.this,"La foto ha sido subida correctamente ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



       }
   });
}
```

**Update Node "Foto"**

```
private  void setActualizarFotodb(final  String Dinnyphoto )
{


//actualiza pero borra el dato

    FirebaseDatabase m_obj=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    final DatabaseReference reference= m_obj.getReference();

    Query query= reference.child("Usuarios/").orderByChild("smsVeri").equalTo(user.getUid());

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot nodo=dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
            String key=nodo.getKey();
            String path="/"+dataSnapshot.getKey()+"/"+key;
            HashMap<String,Object> result =new HashMap<>();
            result.put("foto",Dinnyphoto);
            reference.child(path).updateChildren(result).isSuccessful();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

in firebase the only notification of update is a "Yellow square" in the node "Foto". When I compile my app and click the button to update the "Foto" node, but the value returns to the previous state in a few seconds. For example: Foto=0, new Value="uri", seconds later= 0.000032 s Foto=0.

Comment: Please add the code in text, instead of picture

Comment: Thanks, now the code stay in the format answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Usuarios").orderByChild("smsVeri").equalTo(user.getUid());
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ds.child("foto").getRef().setValue(Dinnyphoto);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

As you can see, you can use `setValue()` method directly on the reference.

Comment: the problem persist, whein i run the code the value Foto="0" change for Foto="uri" but 0,00052 secondas later the value return to Foto="0"

Comment: What value holds `Dinnyphoto`, an uri?